# Geopandas tick labels from a diferent coordinate system

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas

I have a GeoDataFrame that includes points with the relevant geometries (coordinates system WGS84 EPSG:4326)

```
gdf:
Name      x     y   Coordinates
E   -4.375  51.5    POINT (-4.375000000000008 51.49999999999999)
N   -5.000  52.0    POINT (-4.999999999999994 52)
NE  -4.375  52.0    POINT (-4.375000000000008 52)
NW  -5.625  52.0    POINT (-5.625000000000006 52)
S   -5.000  51.0    POINT (-4.999999999999994 50.99999999999999)
SE  -4.375  51.0    POINT (-4.375000000000008 50.99999999999999)
SW  -5.625  51.0    POINT (-5.625000000000006 50.99999999999999)
W   -5.625  51.5    POINT (-5.625000000000006 51.49999999999999)
```

I would like to plot with a background map tiles served from openstreetmap. I understand in order to do that in need to change the coordinate system to Pseudo-Mercator WGS84 EPSG:3857. Then request the tile with contextily.

```
gdf = gdf.to_crs(epsg=3857)
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = gdf.total_bounds
url = 'http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/tileZ/tileX/tileY.png'
basemap, extent = ctx.bounds2img(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, zoom=8, url=url)
```

And then plot the basmap and the points

```
ax = gdf.plot(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.imshow(basemap, extent=extent, interpolation='bilinear')
```

This works fine but I would like the ticks labels to be of the original coordinate system (EPSG:4326). I was thinking that I could `get_xticklabels` and `get_yticklabels` and then do coordinate transformation with gdal but there mast be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to reproject image extent to WGS84 before using it for plotting:

```
import pyproj

xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = gdf.to_crs(epsg=3857).total_bounds
url = 'http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/tileZ/tileX/tileY.png'
basemap, extent = ctx.bounds2img(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, zoom=8, url=url)

reproject = lambda x, y: pyproj.transform(pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:3857'),
                                          pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4326'), x, y)
x1, y1 = reproject(extent[0], extent[2])
x2, y2 = reproject(extent[1], extent[3])
wgs84_extent = x1, x2, y1, y2

ax = gdf.plot(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.imshow(basemap, extent=wgs84_extent, interpolation='bilinear')
```

Hence no need to manually change labels on the map.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Not what I was expecting but better than what I was trying.